# Can't change type of plot in plot() for data.frame (that is not only numeric) in R

Tags: r, plot, graphics

How is it possible to change type/color etc. in `plot()` if `data.frame()` is not only numeric?

Example:

```
a<-data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=1:3)
plot(a,type="o",col="blue")
```

results in:

[image]

whereas

```
a<-data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c"),col2=1:3)
plot(a,type="o",col="blue")
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: Calling `plot` on the second "data.frame" ends up calling `plot.factor`. `?plot.factor` explains the `...` arguments used. In this case `boxplot` is called and `...` should be arguments of `boxplot`. Essentially, you're calling something like `boxplot(1, type = "o", col = "blue")`; perhaps you'll need to revise the arguments you use for changing the style of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon @alexis_laz's comment, you could hack your way out of this by initializing an invisible boxplot and consequently plotting your data on it.

```
 # set border argument of boxplot() to "white"
 plot(a, border = "white")

 # add points to your plot
 points(a$col2 ~ a$col1, col = "blue", type= "o")
```

[image]